# how to bind this in a recursive function inside of a function in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, this, bind

can someone tell me how to make this work in the loop fuction? how can I bind the loop function to constructor?

```
class Cookcoo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            test:false
        }
        this.onPlay=this.onPlay.bind(this)
    }
    onPlay(){
            (function loop() {
            let randomTime = Math.round(Math.random() * 3000) + 500;
            setTimeout(()=> {
                this.setState({test:true}); 
                setTimeout(()=>this.setState({test:false}),500)
                loop();
            }, randomTime);

        }());
    }
```

Comment: one simple solution is `let that = this;` and use `that` inside loop function.

Comment: perfect, thank you very much

Comment: You could also declare loop with a fat arrow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is use a extra variable to store the reference of `this` (class context) and use that variable inside loop function.

Like this:

```
onPlay(){

    let that = this;

    (function loop() {
        let randomTime = Math.round(Math.random() * 3000) + 500;
        setTimeout(()=> {
            that.setState({test:true}); 
            setTimeout(()=>that.setState({test:false}),500)
            loop();
        }, randomTime);
    }());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `bind` the self executing function and then call the inner function with `.call()` like

```
onPlay() {
    (function loop() {
      let randomTime = Math.round(Math.random() * 3000) + 500;
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(this);
        this.setState({ test: true });
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ test: false }, console.log(this.state.test)), 500)
        loop.call(this);
      }, randomTime);

    }.bind(this)());
  }
```